# ORDER BY over secondary index in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, columnstore, nosql

I'm evaluating Cassandra usage for a solution which will need to query a Partition Key and get top 100 results sorted by priority column, which will not be in Clustered Key. I only query by shard key.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
shard_key int,
enity_id int,
priority int, 
PRIMARY KEY ((shard_key), entity_id)
);
CREATE INDEX prio ON my_table (priority);
```

Can I write an efficient CQL query like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE shard_key=1 ORDER BY priority LIMIT 100
```

Is it possible in Cassandra or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: Which Cassandra version are you using ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Does not matter, it can be any. Update: I forgot to mention I only query by shard key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Cassandra 3.0 introduced Materialized View**
If you are using cassandra 3.0 or upper version, you can use Materialized  view to order by non primary key

Create a Materialized  view like this one :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_table_view AS
    SELECT shard_key, priority, entity_id
    FROM my_table
    WHERE shard_key IS NOT NULL AND priority IS NOT NULL AND entity_id IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (shard_key, priority, entity_id);
```

Suppose you have these data on my_table :

```
 shard_key | entity_id | priority
-----------+-----------+----------
         1 |        10 |      100
         1 |        11 |      101
         1 |        12 |      102
         1 |        13 |      103
         2 |        20 |      200
```

Now you can query like this one :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_view WHERE shard_key = 1 ORDER BY priority ASC LIMIT 100;
```

The output will be :

```
 shard_key | priority | entity_id
-----------+----------+-----------
         1 |      100 |        10
         1 |      101 |        11
         1 |      102 |        12
         1 |      103 |        13
```

Comment: just one question before I accept the answer - This means that you cannot order by non-key column even you have an index on it and data resides in one partion key?

Comment: @Cortlendt You can't use order by on indexed field

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you may want to consider [Stratio’s Lucene indexes](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index) to order by any indexed column.